# Register COM Component for Classic ASP

Tags: dll, com, asp-classic, activex, windows-server-2008-x64

I'm upgrading an old Windows 2003 server (32-bit) with IIS 6 to a Windows 2008 server (64-bit) with IIS 7.5. I'm in the process of installing necessary DLLs on the new machine (I only need two). The first one worked fine. The second one, ASPIMAGE.DLL is causing some trouble.

Here's what I've done (same process that worked for XZIP.DLL):

- Move ASPIMAGE.DLL to C:\Windows\SYSWOW64
- `C:\Windows\SYSWOW64\regsvr32.exe C:\Windows\SYSWOW64\ASPIMAGE.DLL` - I get a prompt saying "DLLRegisterServer in ASPIMAGE.DLL succeeded". I've run this multiple times - I hope that's not an issue.
- Set "Enable 32-Bit Application" to True in the Application pool. Restarted the Site and AppPool just to be sure.
- Attempt running code (which works fine on the Win2003 machine):

> I get this error:
>
> Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800703e6'
>
> Server.CreateObject Failed
>
> /scripts/update/resize.asp, line 2
>
> 800703e6

Note that I've also tried this as a replacement, and I have the same issue (it looks like it registers fine, but the code can't see it):
http://code.google.com/p/aspnetimage/

Any ideas what the issue is? It's strange to me, because it seems like it registers fine, but ASP can't find it.

Comment: Error code 800703e6 means "Invalid access to memory location." and as the link you refer to says, this component seems to have bugs and no longer works.  Are you sure that you are getting the exact same error when using the replacement component?

Comment: Right, I guess I'm just confused as to why the same exact file works on my 2003 box. There's some sort of incompatibility there.

You're right, I'm not getting the same exact error for the other component, it's "80070002".

Had suspicions that it was a permissions issue, but no avail even after granting Read and Execute to IUSR.

Worth noting that I ran a vbscript as Administrator `Set Image = CreateObject("AspNetImage.NetImage")` and get this error: `test.vbs(1, 1) (null): The system cannot find the file
 specified.`

Comment: I was actually able to get the object to create successfully. Unfortunately this replacement object doesn't seem to support Image.MaxX and MaxY properties. :(

Comment: Fortunately I was able to do a work-around with some pure ASP code.

Comment: Man, you saved my a*s, I was about to give up on my problem with CAPICON dll not being detected inside classic ASP app, but at the last minute I found your post and read that there is a settings in application pool to enable 32 bit. That one solved my problem. God bless you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by using AspNetImage as a replacement in conjunction with `LoadPicture()`: http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_loadpicture.asp.

http://code.google.com/p/aspnetimage/